# How to avoid duplicate rows in SQL after auto-incrementing a column

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I use the `bulk insert` syntax to upload a daily file to `SQL`, and currently look for ways to avoid row `duplicates` after `auto-incrementing` an `ID` column and setting it as the `primary key`. As an illustration of the table used:

```
CREATE TABLE dupli
(
ID int IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
period date NOT NULL,
fruits varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
num    int NOT NULL,
)
```

Assuming `dupli.csv` contains:

`4/20/2011, apple, 5`

`SQL` naturally retrieves following the file upload:

```
1000¦2011-04-20¦apple¦5¦
```

**The loophole**: If someone, by mistake, uploads the same file without checking `ex-ante` that some data exists as of `2011-04-20` then a duplicate row is created as

```
1001¦2011-04-20¦apple¦5¦
```

and so on...

This looks normal as `ID` has been `auto-incremented`. However I wonder if there are ways , to keep `ID` auto-incremented while avoiding the duplicate row? meaning I could get:

```
1000¦2011-04-20¦apple¦5¦
1001¦2011-04-21¦apple¦5¦
```

...

**but never**

```
1000¦2011-04-20¦apple¦5¦
1001¦2011-04-20¦apple¦5¦
```

Otherwise the `bulk insert` does not execute.

The purpose is to avoid creating a `function` that checks if pre-existing data exists on a daily basis before executing the `bulk insert` (*only once*). So far this is the only way around I can think of to preserve the structure of the above table and avoid duplicates.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have to insert directly in to the production table? Why not insert in to a holding table first, check for duplicates, then insert. The holding table can be truncated after each insert. But can still have the indexes required to optimise the checking.

Comment: Direct insert sounds the easiest implementation to me, being aware that the `easiest` method is not always the `best` efficient approach, reason why I've been stuck with the `duplicate` matter.

Comment: How are you initiating the `bulk insert`? Stored Procedure called from a Job, another Process/Application, or are you just executing a script? You can use a temporary table or a table variable within the Procedure. With temporary tables you can still apply indexes as required, but doing so with table variables is limited.

Comment: Agree with @BeaglesEnd that [staging](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1437794-391-1.aspx) is probably the way to go.  Another option is to import via SSIS.  There are several ways SSIS can deduplicate the source data.

Comment: @BeaglesEnd: `bulk insert` is initiated through a `C# method`. reason why i mentioned in the thread that as a `solution of last resort` I could make a `function` that checks if  data pre-exists before executing the `bulk`. However I was curious to see if there exists more robust `method`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create, then bulk insert to a temporary table. After that you can issue a simple merge or (even simpler) outer join insert statement to update dupli. Once the connection is disposed and the connection lost, the temp table will be dropped. So there is no tidying up to be done.

```
 using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Strings.connection_string))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand() { Connection = connection })
        {
          command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE #dupli (period date, fruits varchar(MAX), num int, primary key (period, fruits))";
          connection.Open();
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();

          //Now do your bulk insert to #dupli

          // issue a merge statement (or simple left outer join insert) to update the target table
         /*
         insert into dupli(period, fruits, num)
         select #dupli.period, #dupli.fruits, #dupli.num
         from #dupli left outer join dupli
         on #dupli.period = dupli.period
         and #dupli.fruits = dupli.fruits
         where dupli.ID is null
         */
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you certain the advocated solution guarantees the absence of any duplicates after executing many times the code on `dupli.csv` as illustrated above?

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it a little clearer. Adding a primary key to the temp table ensures that there are no duplicates there (shifting responsibility back to your client app). I believe that the code will execute in a transaction - so even if you have thousands of threads trying to insert the data, you won't ever get duplicates in the output.

Comment: Thank you, as your latest `suggestion` / `edit` is intuitively making more sense to me.